# Trapping "echo off" stty on linux terminals

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, command-line-arguments

I occasionally need to be extra sure that the password I type is the right one (e.g. because I already made one mistake & the next one will lock me out for 15 minutes) so I am after something like the password revealer on android for Linux/U*x terminals. Ideally it would be something like (I know I could get around this specific example with ssh-pass: but that would also end up in shell history, so just bear with me):

```
$ preveal ssh admin@my_firewal
Password: secrete_revealed
cisco>
```

"Preveal" should trap the stty controls turning echo off (or, whatever) for the command duration (now ssh may be a bad example, but the intent should be clear).

I know, "bad security something something" but I already explained the rationale above. cut+paste is meh, as extra steps are needed to verify that what has been cut is what's intended. script(1), besides being a PITA, does not work.

Does anyone know of such a tool?

Comment: Learn to use a password manager, a key chain, setup public key authentication for `ssh`. In addition as you're asking for a software recommendation this could be considered [off-topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) though you do show that you did a tiny bit more.

Comment: @Seth I use all of these (been doing that for the last 20 years), including the excellent 'pass' CLI password manager (check it out, it's good & FOSS)  There are corner cases where they do not fit the bill (the question shows the foremost). I understand how this galls a lot of people, but then the same applies to the eye icon on mobile devices. I also fail to see how asking "is there a command Y that does X" amounts to be asking for SW reccomandation.

Comment: Because your last sentence is asking for a tool rather than a command. In addition I don't see how the above would be a corner case for any of the mentioned tools. I addition it's supported to have public key authentication on [cisco](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/110946/ssh-using-public-key-authentication-ios-and-big-outputs) as well.

Comment: I have to do this for devices that either do not support PKA (say lowend zyxel), or on which I do not have full access (can login, cannot cfg), or have just been reinstalled and PK has not yet been deployed, or that are accessed with means other than ssh.  There are uncountable number of commands which follow the traditional practice of setting tty in noecho when asking for a secret. as I specified in the text, ssh is just an example. But don't take my word for it, you are welcome to share a day at the data center with me and see for yourself.

Comment: A trip to Italy sure would be fun. :D I guess I focused to much on your example which is kind of bad (IMHO), so sorry. Anyway, you found a solution. The [github](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) has some alternatives, though they seem to target slightly different scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

And the answer is:

```
 rlwrap -a <<command args>>
```

has worked on all the bones I threw it so far - including the ssh example.

Comment: According to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap) `rlwrap` does have it's own history and the `-a` switch will write (in your case) the password(s) as clear text to the history file. You could try to use `-s -1` or `-s 0` to prevent this. See also [this](http://catern.com/2014/02/14/rlwrap-history.html).